How to update individual line items in Shopify cart when the same product is added with multiple quantities?
I'm working on a Shopify store where I need to allow users to customize each individual cart item separately, even if they have added the same product multiple times with different quantities.
For example, a customer can add a product to the cart with a quantity of 2 but would like to personalize each item (e.g., sending cakes to different people by adding From - For products might be same and in bulk quantity).
I have split the quantity in the cart visually using Liquid like this:
{%- for i in (1..item.quantity) -%}
  <!-- Displaying each item separately -->
{%- endfor -%}

However, when I try to update the properties for a specific "split" item (via the line property in the Shopify cart API), it updates all the items in that line instead of just one.
Here’s a snippet of how I'm trying to update the line item in the cart:
const item_variant_id = this.querySelector('input[name="item_variant_id"]');
const item_variant_key = this.querySelector('input[name="item_variant_key"]');
const line_item_index = this.querySelector('input[name="line_item_index"]');

const body = JSON.stringify({
  line: line_item_index.value,  // 1-based index of the line item in the cart
  quantity: 2,  // just for testing
  properties: {
    "FROM": nombreField.value,
    "FOR": celularField.value
  }
});

Screenshot Splitted Cart Items

Sounds like shopify itself did not add multiple "lines" to its internal cart representation in the first place, and you are just "faking" them when you create your output ...?

No, if a user adds several quantities of the same product, we replicate it just for preview, with a button to "personalise" the item.

But what good is splitting this up for display purposes only? If shopify works like pretty much any other shopping cart system in this regard - which I would assume - then it will not create multiple order positions, just because you add the same product multiple times in multiple steps. No, it will simply find the already existing entry for the product ID, and then increase or decrease the quantity of that entry.

The aim for splitting it to show the "Personalize" button. So, is there a way we can uniquely identify each item to add custom properties? I have attached the screenshot on the post.

Probably not, as long as you simply keep adding "the same" product to the cart. This will likely have to make use of variations, or something like that. A quick research suggests there are several plugins/extensions available to provide "customized" products, maybe go and check how they are doing it?

In Shopify, the Cart object groups line items with the same variant ID and properties together. If you want to treat each individual item as separate (for instance, adding the same product multiple times but allowing for unique customizations), you need to ensure each line item has a unique property, even if it's the same product variant.
The key to solving this problem is to use Shopify's Ajax Cart API and add a unique identifier (line item property) when adding the product to the cart. This way, Shopify will treat them as separate line items, even if they have the same product variant ID.
You can implement this by doing:

Each time a product is added to the cart, generate a unique identifier (e.g., a random number or a timestamp) to distinguish it from other instances of the same product.

And then, when adding the product to the cart via Ajax API, include this unique identifier in the properties field.


The below code snippet is an example that you can refer to:
let variantData = null;
let identifier = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000000000) + 1000000000; // Generate a random 10-digit number, just for your refernece

variantData = {
  id: variant_id, // Product's variant ID
  quantity: quantity, // Quantity to add
  properties: {
    _lineitem_identifier: identifier // Unique identifier to differentiate items
  }
};

console.log('Variant data:', variantData);

try {
  const response = await fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(variantData)
  });

  const responseResult = await response.json();
  console.log('The product has been added to cart successfully:', responseResult);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error:', error);
}

I hope this helps you!
